# Constant Functions Over Global Variables?

Tags: javascript

Global variables are bad, hopefully we are pretty much all agreed on that. But are global functions that only ever return one thing less bad?

```
var foo = 42; // this is bad
function foo() { return 42; } // less bad?
```

I get the feeling I can't be the first one to think of doing this, but am having difficulties thinking of the drawbacks.

Comment: But then your *function* has to be global.

Comment: Yes it's considered "bad practice", but how is a global function any different in your mind than any other type of global variable?

Comment: Prior to ES6 and classes, every function would have been global (a method on `window`) and that was ok, but a global variable (a property of `window`) wasn't. The difference is, I guess, my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have a global variable (and it is a variable, not a constant), the only difference is that the value of that variable is a function.

There are no benefits, and you have the overhead of calling the function whenever you want to get the value.

If you want a constant, then use a constant.

```
const foo = 42;
```

This still has the drawbacks of being a global and you should still aim to define your variables and constants in as narrow a scope as you can.

Comment: Other drawback,  Engine needs to support const. ;)

Comment: If it's on the browser, make sure to use: `"use strict";` as your first line in the top most control block

Comment: @espascarello There are things like babel, webpack and browserify that allow backwards compatibility, and most modern browsers already support many common ES6 keywords anyway. That's not really a drawback.

Comment: Thank you, you have confirmed my initial thoughts. When you say, "it is a variable, not a constant," how is the value of `foo()` mutable? Just declare another function and call it `foo`?

Answer (score 1):

The main disadvantage of having globals (functions or variables) is that their names can collapse with other libraries or frameworks that you use in your application. 
Also they negatively affect code reusability and code distribution. 
Due to these reasons you should avoid using globals. Instead you should encapsulate these globals in some namespace and you should try your best to make the namespace name unique enough so that it does not conflict with any library or framework.